# Selecionar uma option e enviar ID

Tags: php, html, html5, laravel

Amigos bom dia. Tenho uma dúvida.. preciso que em uma view eu selecione uma opção que contém o nome do motorista porém preciso que no controlador eu receba o ID desse motorista e não o request com o nome dele. ***Uma outra opção que pensei é um campo  que visualmente mostre o nome do motorista mas que por baixo esteja enviando o ID dele.*** Abaixo tem o meu código:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="margin-bottom-10">
                    <label class="control-label">Motorista</label>                                    
                    <select class="bs-select form-control" name="nome_motorista" data-width="100px">
                    @foreach($motorista as $m)                      
                        <option value="motorista">{{$m->nome}}</option>
                    @endforeach                                                                        
                    </select>                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

Observem que na opção o usuário vai selecionar um motorista específico, mas eu preciso que no controlador eu receba o ID desse motorista. Alguém pode me ajudar? **Se alguém souber como mostrar uma opção somente visualmente para o usuário e essa opção escolhida envie um dado X para o banco, eu agradeço, também resolveria minha questão!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar o código do motorista, é só você alterar o atributo `value` no option e passar o id em vez de apenas "motorista".

Você pode tentar algo mais ou menos assim:

```html
<select class="bs-select form-control" name="nome_motorista" data-width="100px">
    @foreach($motorista as $m)                      
        <option value="{{$m->id}}">{{$m->nome}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Simples e eficaz, obrigado Luciano, o juízo já tá queimando, nem pensei nisso. Abraços